# C# WebForms multiple HighCharts

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, highcharts

Всем привет.
На основе данных из бд строю график.
Использую библиотеку HighCharts.
Необходимо выгрузить 2 графика на страницу, но выводит последний.
Просмотрел html код, создаётся только 1 div c id = 'chart_container' и script renderTo:'chart_container' соответственно второй скрипт записывается на место первого:(

Как вывести несколько графиков на страницу?

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
```

...

```
chrtMyChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

И в коде:

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts("chart1")
ltrChart1.Text = chart1.ToHtmlString();

var chart2 = new Highcharts("chart2")
ltrChart2.Text = chart2.ToHtmlString();
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь